Continuously monitor a process and all its children with `top`?
I want to run a process that spawns children, e.g.,
for i in {1..4}; do
  sh -c 'echo $$; for j in {1..3}; do
    sh -c "echo ...\$\$; sleep 1"
  done'
done

and I would like to monitor the CPU and memory usage every 2 seconds with top.

I can monitor its resource usage with top -p <PID>, but this doesn't account for the children.
I can monitor all running processes just with top, but this is too much information.
I can precompute a list of PIDs, then pass all of them to top, but the process could then spawn new children, which would not be accounted for.

How can I get a top snapshot every 2 seconds of just the process I'm running and any processes it spawns?
Someone asked a similar question here, but it was about summarizing this information into a single number, after the process finishes. My question is about continuously monitoring the processes while they’re still going.

In your example you're running an apptainer container, which might have a specific solution (need to check later, not sure about it). Will an answer for container help, or are you looking for a generic solution?

Also, do you need this for a process that's already running? Or do you want to monitor the children of a process you're going to run (so maybe I can provide a certain way to execute the process that would help)? And of course, I assume that you won't insist on top and you could settle on another tool that provides live monitoring for memory/CPU?

Good questions! (1) I want the more generic solution—I just threw apptainer in because it spawns a handful of processes. I should change it to a more general example. (2) I was thinking of a process already running, but in my specific use case either works.

I don't have a suggestion for how to make top output only a particular process and its child processes, but after you have that figured out, you may need to log the output of top to a file over minutes/hours.  This answer to another question can give you ideas on how to accomplish that part.

Since I've also wanted a similar capability, I wrote a script that does that.
The advantage of the script is that top is running continuously, so it actually shows the CPU consumption of the last interval (3 seconds by default, but could be changed with the -d secs parameter).
The previous answers were running top once each cycle, and in that case top only shows the CPU consumption at that exact moment. The 3 seconds average is more accurate.
It also solves the problem with top not able to receive more than 20 pids.
This script requires setting top in "Forest View Mode"1 : You'll need to start top, press V to toggle the forest mode, and than press W to write your current setting to your $HOME/.toprc configuration file2 .
The script3 runs top continuously (by default), with all the process running on the host, and does some parsing using sed to only present the required pid and it's children.
Here's the code. I haven't done any serious tests and didn't bother to think about corner cases, I just made it work. Maybe I'll improve it in the future.
#!/bin/bash

usage() {
  echo "Usage: toptree.sh <PID> [top options]"
  echo "You need to make sure your 'top' is configured to a tree mode"
  exit
}

cleanup() {
  ps -p $toppid >& /dev/null && kill $toppid
  rm -rf "$FIFO_DIR"
  trap - EXIT INT TERM
}

trap cleanup EXIT INT TERM

parse_top() {
  local pid=$1
  ps -p $toppid >& /dev/null || exit # top is not running anymore
  sed -un -e $'/^top/,/PID/{p; /PID/{q}}' # print the header of top  
  local parent=$( 
    sed -nu \
      -e "/^ *$pid/{p; q}" \
      -e '/^top/{q 1}' # if we reached the next top cycle,
                       # it means we didn't find the parent process
  ) || exit 0  # sed didn't find the process
               # The process is probably finished

  # Next, we want to find only the children of the process
  # Since this is in tree form, we want only processes
  # with greater indentation than the parent.
  # we catch the spaces before the branch (`-) of the parent
  local indent=$(sed -nr 's/.*[^ ](  +)`-.*/\1/p' <<< "$parent")
  
  [ -z "$indent" ] && exit # Didn't find the branch marker
                           # Happens if top is not in tree mode
  
  sed "s/$indent\`-/ \`-/" <<< "$parent" # Remove indentation
  
  # Now we're printing all the children
  # until we reach a process in a another process tree
  # (ie, the branch level is equal or smaller than parent) 
  # than the parent we're monitoring

  sed -unr "
    s/ $indent\`-/ \`-/p
    t next # if indentation >  parent's, next cycle
    q      # if indentation <= parent's, outside branch. quit.
    :next" 
  echo 
}

is_pid() {
  local pid=$1
  if [ -n "$pid" ] && [ "$pid" -eq "$pid" ] 2>/dev/null
  then
    if ! ps -p $pid >& /dev/null
    then
      echo $pid is not running
      exit 1 
    fi
  else
    echo $pid should be a number
    usage
  fi
}


PID=$1
is_pid "$PID"

shift
FIFO_DIR=$(mktemp -d /tmp/toptree.XXXXXX)
FIFO="$FIFO_DIR/fifo"
mkfifo "$FIFO" 

top -b -w 150 "${@}" > "$FIFO" & toppid=$!

while parse_top $PID; do :; done < "$FIFO"

Example:
$ toptree.sh
Usage: toptree.sh <PID> [top options]
You need to make sure your 'top' is configured to a tree mode

$ toptree.sh 17349 -d 2 -n 2
top - 20:29:27 up 90 days,  6:10, 396 users,  load average: 0.16, 0.14, 0.10
Tasks: 1926 total,   1 running, 1925 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.4 us,  2.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 96.6 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.4 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:  39455878+total, 17768724 used, 37679008+free,    47308 buffers
KiB Swap: 39427174+total,        0 used, 39427174+free. 11275700 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S   %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
17349 aviro     20   0   12096   8136   2976 S  0.000 0.002   0:00.32 `- bash
15817 aviro     20   0    6988   2620   2388 S  0.000 0.001   0:00.00    `- bash
15820 aviro     20   0    2500   1268   1188 S  0.000 0.000   0:00.00        `- sleep
15821 aviro     20   0    2500   1268   1188 S  0.000 0.000   0:00.00        `- sleep
15818 aviro     20   0    6988   2620   2388 S  0.000 0.001   0:00.00    `- bash
15822 aviro     20   0    2500   1268   1188 S  0.000 0.000   0:00.00        `- sleep
15823 aviro     20   0    2500   1268   1188 S  0.000 0.000   0:00.00        `- sleep
15819 aviro     20   0    2500   1268   1188 S  0.000 0.000   0:00.00    `- sleep

top - 20:29:29 up 90 days,  6:10, 396 users,  load average: 0.16, 0.14, 0.10
Tasks: 1926 total,   1 running, 1925 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.2 us,  0.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:  39455878+total, 17768724 used, 37679008+free,    47308 buffers
KiB Swap: 39427174+total,        0 used, 39427174+free. 11275700 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S   %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
17349 aviro     20   0   12096   8136   2976 S  0.000 0.002   0:00.32 `- bash
15817 aviro     20   0    6988   2620   2388 S  0.000 0.001   0:00.00    `- bash
15820 aviro     20   0    2500   1268   1188 S  0.000 0.000   0:00.00        `- sleep
15821 aviro     20   0    2500   1268   1188 S  0.000 0.000   0:00.00        `- sleep
15818 aviro     20   0    6988   2620   2388 S  0.000 0.001   0:00.00    `- bash
15822 aviro     20   0    2500   1268   1188 S  0.000 0.000   0:00.00        `- sleep
15823 aviro     20   0    2500   1268   1188 S  0.000 0.000   0:00.00        `- sleep
15819 aviro     20   0    2500   1268   1188 S  0.000 0.000   0:00.00    `- sleep

Notice you can add any flag to the script that would be passed to top. For instance, if you want to see the full command lines, add -c:
$ toptree.sh 19140 -c -n1
top - 20:40:52 up 90 days,  6:21, 398 users,  load average: 0.24, 0.13, 0.10
Tasks: 1930 total,   1 running, 1929 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.8 us,  2.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 96.4 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:  39455878+total, 17782400 used, 37677638+free,    45796 buffers
KiB Swap: 39427174+total,        0 used, 39427174+free. 11276956 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S   %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
19140 aviro     20   0    6988   2624   2388 S  0.000 0.001   0:00.00 `- bash -c sleep 5 & sleep 5
19141 aviro     20   0    2500   1268   1188 S  0.000 0.000   0:00.00    `- sleep 5
19142 aviro     20   0    2500   1268   1188 S  0.000 0.000   0:00.00    `- sleep 5

1I wish top had more command line options, that would allow starting the forest view mode from the command line without having to change the default view, but it is what it is.
2By issuing the 'W' command just before quitting top, you will be able restart later in exactly that same state
3It might have been more elegant to do that in python, but oh well.

Since you mention in a comment that preparing something before you launch the mother process would generally be feasible, and because your example launches a container, which probably already does that:
Simply use Linux cgroups to monitor (and if wanted, control and limit) the resources used by your group of related processes.
It's pretty simple: if your process is in a cgroup, then its children are spawned in the same. So, put your mother process in a cgroup of their own (that's "basically free", by default a new cgroup inherits everything from the parent cgroup). Then, regularly poll the processes in that cgroup from the cgroupsv2 controllers, and display them. The whole game looks like this:
#!/usr/bin/python3
# Copyright 2024 Marcus Müller
# SPDX-License-Identifier: EUPL-1.2
#
# I was about to write this in *sh, but honestly, doesn't pay.
# Let's do this in python. I'm not sure you'd understand shell script
# better than python, anyways, and we're about to handle a few strings,
# so, let's simply not do that in a shell language

from subprocess import run
from time import sleep
import argparse


def pids_of_cgroup(cgroup: str) -> list:
    with open(f"/sys/fs/cgroup/{cgroup}/cgroup.procs",
              "r",
              encoding="ascii") as procs:
        return [int(line) for line in procs.readlines()]


def cgroup_from_pid(pid: int) -> str:
    with open(f"/proc/{pid}/cgroup", "r", encoding="ascii") as cgr_file:
        line = cgr_file.readline().strip()  # just one line
    return line.split(":")[-1]  # last element


def run_program(pids: list, program: str = None) -> None:
    if program is None:
        prog = "top"
    else:
        prog = program
    cmdline = [prog, "-p", ",".join(str(pid) for pid in pids), "-n", "1"]
    if prog == "htop":
        cmdline += ["--tree", "--readonly"]  # tree view

    run(cmdline)


def do_job(mother: int, htop: bool = False, interval: float = 2.0):
    # First argument is the parent PID, we use that to get the cgroup:
    cgroup = cgroup_from_pid(mother)
    program = "htop" if htop else "top"
    first_iter = True
    try:
        while True:
            if not first_iter:
                sleep(interval)
            first_iter = False
            pids = pids_of_cgroup(cgroup)
            run_program(pids, program)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass  # User pressed ctrl+c, quit normally
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"CGroup {cgroup} ceased to exist; quitting.")


if __name__ == "__main__":  # if we're called as freestanding program
    argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="show process stats of all child processes")
    argparser.add_argument("PID",
                           help="Mother process PID", type=int)
    argparser.add_argument(
        "-H", "--htop", help="Use htop instead of top", action='store_true')

    def positive_float(in_str: str) -> float:
        val = float(in_str)
        if val <= 0:
            raise ValueError(f"'{in_str}' has non-positive value {val}")
        return val

    argparser.add_argument("-t", "--interval",
                           help="Time between updates",
                           type=positive_float,
                           default=2.0)
    args = argparser.parse_args()
    do_job(args.PID, htop=args.htop, interval=args.interval)



Save this to a file, make the file executable (chmod 755 filename), and run it with the PID of the parent process (/path/to/filename 1234).
This will almost certainly work with anything that is a container already (so, flatpak, podman and docker containers, apptainer containers,…).
It's super easy to start something in a cgroup of its own:
systemd-run --user --scope program_you_wanted_to_run

(of course, if the program happens to be actually a service, by all means, remove the --scope and run as service; if it's to be run as system, not as user program, remove the --user. Ideally, if it's a service, you'd just actually write the 6 lines of config to make it a fully fledged systemd service with its own scope)

The problem is that top can only get a maximum of 20 pids through -p, so if there are more that 20 pids in the cgroup, top would fail.

@aviro hence the option to run with htop instead.

FWIW, the -n / --max-iterations option was added to htop at the last version, 3.3.0, that was released only 5 months ago. On my workstation I have 3.2.2 where it doesn't work.

@aviro ha! interestig. Didn't realize it was this recent!

This is a great answer, so I really hate to take the check mark away. I did so just because aviro’s answer is more general and can apply to an already-running process.

@wobtax no need to apologize when you get an answer that fits your needs more!

There are a number of options.

For any visible field, you can filter on that field.  An obvious candidate is TTY=pts/*number*.  Note that you will need to turn on display of TTY.  One initiates this filtering by pressing o, or using O to add another filter.  You can isolate a command to be the only thing on a tty with a number of commands, including screen command and xterm -e command, and ssh -t localhost command (which also has the advantage of not losing the output).
You can put the entire top into a tree view mode using V, and then close unwanted parent nodes with v.  This should allow you to restrict it enough just to see your command, though it may take some time to restrict it.  This might need to be combined with other things, as there is typically only one or two full trees.
You could run the command in its own user, and the restrict display with u.

These techniques, or a combination thereof, may give you the results you want.
Edit: For ease of setup, you might want to write something like tty;sleep 10 at the top of your script...  or even in another script that execs your target script.

If you don't mind running your program in a different user namespace using unshare, then you can filter in top according to the user namespace.
$ unshare -r
$ readlink /proc/$$/ns/user
user:[4026532793]

You also run unshare -r <COMMAND>, and then look for it's user namespace with it's pid.
Now, in order to view all the processes in the user namespace in top:

Press f to choose a field

Using the Down/Up arrow keys, navigate to nsUSER (USER namespace Inode).

Toggle it on by pressing the space key

Press "q" to get back to the main top view.

Press "O" in order to trigger the filter, and filter the processes according to the user namespace
add filter #1 (case sensitive) as: [!]FLD?VAL nsUSER=4026532793


Done.



nice! Yeah, that's an extremely elegant way. If you were root, you could also just unshare --pid and run top/htop from within the thus created PID namespace.

@MarcusMüller yeah, I thought about it. You don't actually require root, as long as you're running in a private user namespace where you have uid 0 inside. At first I wanted to write out this way as well, but I thought this might be a bit too complicated. I may add that solution to this answer as well, but I'm working on another answer from a different approach now.

I honestly think your answer is fine that way. You could add exactly the sentence from your comment above and  would have mentioned it enough for an interested party to be able to understand or research what you mean.

What I came up with for my own question, not as nice as the others people have posted:
#!/bin/bash
# Tested with `top` from `procps-ng 4.0.3` and `pstree 23.6`.

# Print the ID of the given process together with IDs of all its descendants
get_pid_with_descendants() {
  pid="$1"
  pstree -ap "$pid" | sed -r 's/,([0-9]+).*|./\1/g'
}

# Monitor the given PID and its descendants every k seconds
monitor_with_top() {
  pid="$1"
  k="$2"

  # While the process is running...
  while kill -s 0 "$pid" 2>/dev/null; do
    pids=( $(get_pid_with_descendants $pid) )

    # Print a top screen for all processes in this list
    top -bn1 "${pids[@]/#/-p }"

    # Wait k seconds
    sleep "$k"
  done
}


Then running monitor_with_top <my_PID> 2 prints the expected top screen every 2 seconds.
(Edit: oh, right, as aviro pointed out, top will only work with up to 20 PIDs passed this way. Following Marcus Müller’s answer, you can use htop with --tree --readonly instead.)

I find your way to get the pids too complicated, and also not entirely reliable, since it is possible that at some point the session id of one of the children changes for any reason. I would use pstree, something like: pstree -ap <pid> | sed -r 's/,([0-9]+).*|./\1/g'

Oh, that’s way simpler and more reliable. Thanks!!
